# Basic Express/Node Function Syntax Not Working

Tags: node.js, express, passenger, dreamhost

On my Mac, I can create a simple "Hello World" Node/Express app like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Yo')
})

app.listen(3000, () => 
  console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
)
```

It works great. But when I install my Node app on my web host (DreamHost), I make sure I'm on the same version of Node and NPM, and I do `npm install` and then restart the server.

Passenger complains about the syntax:

```
/home/labrumco/progressbox.net/app.js:9
app.listen(3000, () => 
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Why would it reject that syntax? My guess is some kind of syntax dependency, but I'm too new to Node to know the difference. :)

If I change it to this it works:

```
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
})
```

`function(){` works instead of `() =>`

Why is this happening?

**--- Update ---**

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Clifton Labrum",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your `node -v`?

Comment: And please post your package.json

Comment: My Node version is `10.9.0`

Comment: Make sure the node version of your host is at least 8

Comment: package.json posted above in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, and you've run `$ node -v` on the server as well and still get 10.9.0?

Comment: Yes, correct: `10.9.0`. It must be something wrong with the web host, I guess.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I've just encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by informing Passenger of the node version through the `.htaccess` file.

Make sure you follow the guide to use nvm to install your version of node.

```
nvm install v10.18.1
nvm alias default v10.18.1
```

In your project directory, create a file named `.htaccess` and add the following line:

```
PassengerNodejs /home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.1/bin/node
```

**Make sure you replace username with your username and the node version you need**

Then restart the server (`touch tmp/restart.txt`) and Passenger should use the specified version of node.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry that I failed to post a solution. I did exactly what you suggested with the `.htaccess` file. I'm glad it's documented here now for others. : )

Comment: Yeah, thought as much, just wanted to post the solution for others like me :) Cheers